# Passing data between a C# application and a C console application in visual studio while debugging

Tags: c#, c, console, console-application, communication

I am working on an embedded system protocol to communicate from a micro-controller to a computer. The micro-controller code is in C and the computer application is in C#. For debugging purposes, I have the micro-controller portion currently in a visual studio project since it is faster to compile and step through than on the micro-controller directly. I would like to be able to pass data back and forth between my C# application and the C console application and have both running in their own debuggers so I can step through all steps of the communication loop.

I have seen some references that look like this should be possible by redirecting stdin and stdout from the C console application, but all of the examples are when the process is launched from the C# application. Since both application would need to be launched from their VS debug sessions, I am not sure how to get this connection working.

All I need is a way to send a byte array in each direction and receive it in the other application.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
John Vickers

Comment: There are many ways to do inter-process communication in windows. Sockets is my preferred way, other methods are pipes and shared memory. Here is the windows article on IPC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: how do they normally talk to each other?

Comment: if it's a serial port, just use serial, write an adaption layer for your microntroller code to send  serial.  You can then use virtual serial ports to connect them.

Comment: If you don't want virtual serial, then  fake your serial into a tcp connection.  The other approach I have done is compile my C code into a library and then created a managed library.  I did this so I could emulate various peripherial devices (like I2C) and create visualizations and check the code didn't wear flash unecessarily, etc

Comment: one last note, a lot of that style of testing goes away if you unit test in visual studio (I wrote SeaTest for doing unit testing for this kind of thing )  https://github.com/keithn/seatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairn O.,

Thanks for pointing me onto ICP, I hadn't really thought about doing sockets because I assumed it would be complex to do a server in C under Windows. After doing some reading on the different types of ICP, I came across this article:

http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/

It has really simple examples that are working for creating a client and a server in C. This method should work really well for me because it is a direct emulation of one of the connection methods I will have in the micro (USB and RS232 being the other types of connections).

This way I can also test my Ethernet socket connection code in my C# application at the same time, and I don't have to fake it out like I thought I would have to with other methods!

Hope this helps someone else too!

Thanks again,
John Vickers